# Is there a way for streamlit user input to be formatted automatically as currency (include commas, dollar sign)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I'm building my first `streamlit` app. On my sidebar, I have a field for the user to enter a numeric value. This input (originally `st.text_input()` but later `st.number_input()` enable filtering of data (here it is a column of salary) that is displayed.

I've looked but couldn't find a way to format it so that with inputs of 1,000 or above, it automatically adds a comma, so it's human-readable. In addition, if I can add a "$" at the beginning, that would be even better (not crucial though). I suspect this is outside of `streamlit` capability but thought maybe there are fancy ways through its widget to accomplish this.

My code is something like:

```
 st.sidebar.markdown('### Enter a minimum full-time salary:')
```

In this case, I think having an image helps. Here I would like it to show up as $500,000 even when a user enters 500000.

[image: sidebar image]

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I determined that the way to go about this is to use `st.number_input()` instead of `st.text_input()`. There is minimal support with a `format` option though. It's a feature that others have brought up:

Here is more [context](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-make-number-input-display-something-that-looks-like-currency/2264/2). There is this open [GitHub issue](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/1301). When this open issue is resolved, I'll update with final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked into the number formatting, but I have made the following function to add a currency symbol to the `st.number_input`:

```
def add_currency_to_input(label, cur_symbol='€'):
    st.markdown(
        f"""
        <style>
            [aria-label="{label}"] {{
                padding-left: 30px;
            }}
            [data-testid="stNumberInput"]:has([aria-label="{label}"])::before {{
                position: absolute;
                content: "{cur_symbol}";
                left:12px;
                top:8px;
            }}
        </style>
        """,
        unsafe_allow_html=True,
    )
```

Answer (score -2):

A streamlit [number_input](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html#streamlit.number_input) accepts a `format` string that formats a number like printf does.

So you want:

```
st.sidebar.number_input('', format='{:,d}')
```

Using empty string for the label since you appear to be using markdown for the label.

Comment: This does not work. Format is limited to printf style and does not support f-styles. See my answer about this.